# In sql table insert two same values,if insert same value in 3rd time it not allow to insert that record

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
create table sample(id int primary key,name varchar(100))
insert into sample values(1,'a')
,(2,'a')
,(3,'d')
,(4,'b')
,(5,'b')

--insert into sample values(6,'a'),(7,'b')
```

this record is not allow to insert the table.it disply error

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: truncate the table sample & recreate the table & insert the data.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. Also, remove the irrelevant tags (.Net, msbi) and add the tag for the sql server version you are using.

Comment: hi,I am not getting any error.if insert the same record in third time into the table,that record should not be insert into the table.

Comment: So, what you're asking for is *some form of constraint*, such that you *want* it to generate an error when the same `name` value is inserted a third time?

Comment: My requirement is if insert the same value in 3rd time into the table,it could not be insert and i want to  throw a error '3rd Duplicate value is not insert'.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to check the table if the value being inserted is already present in the table twice before the insert statement.

```
--Preparation
DECLARE @sample  TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY --USE IDENTITY to auto increment your primary key
    ,name VARCHAR(100)
)
--Initial Values
INSERT INTO @sample
VALUES
('a')
,('a')
,('d')
,('b')
,('b')

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100)
SET @name = 'a'

IF(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM @sample WHERE name = @name) <= 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @sample
    VALUES (@name)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Error: Name ''' + @name + ''' already exists twice. Only two same values are allowed in name field!'
END
```